# How to match index to index if matches run the script on success

Tags: shell-script

I have a scenario where I'm generating two files **file_1** and **file_2**

file_1 as data

```
125

150
```

file_2 as data

```
125

150
```

Data should match index to index file_1[0] to file_2[0]

**if matches all the values on success**

**my script should run otherwise fail**

```
if []

succes
my script run : wc -l data.txt
else
fail 
exit
```

*How to achieve this index to index match?*

Comment: Under what conditions should the script succeed and fail?  Is this a matter of simply comparing the files? Your files do not seem to contain indexes as such.

Comment: If the files have the same values in the same order, with no excess whitespace, then the whole file is identical. So diff, cmp, cksum, or bash could all test that condition. If the values are the same except for order, then sorting them first would work. If you want extra options (like reporting any differences), that's also easy if you can describe the requirements in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you want, but my interpretation is that this script below covers it.

```
#!/bin/bash
if cmp -s file_1 file_2 >/dev/null; then
    echo success
    wc -l data.txt
else
    echo fail
fi
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use `cmp -s` for when you want to compare two files without looking at the actual differences.

Comment: @steve  i want to compare index to index data if all the value of file 1 match with file 2 then only rum wc -l command their might be scenario like the file1 may have less row data  and file 2 might have more row data

Comment: @Kusalananda - good point, revised.  genip26057 - the index aspect is less than clear, so to get an answer that meets your needs, please revise original question to factor this in, showing example inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: @genip26057 In way is comparing "index to index" different from comparing the two files like how steve is showing? Please put any clarifications in your question, not in comments.